# DNS issue - server IP address could not be found

Tags: dns

My domain (ecokrypt.com) is with godaddy

Yesterday I tried making some changes, after that my DNS has stopped resolving to IP address. I get below error:

```
This site can’t be reached

 ecokrypt.com’s server IP address could not be found.


Search Google for ecokrypt
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

My current setting is as per attached image.

1. Tried clearing my browser history
2. Power off my router box
3. I event tried changing it to route 53 name servers, but I always get above error.
4. If I use direct IP - I do see my website (partially as without DNS name it will give me error)
5. Tried pinging ecokrypt.com from my local machine, I get unknown host

I am just unable to understand what is wrong.

[image: My current settings]

UPDATES# Tried dig command as suggested below and it seems ok. So looks like I have to wait till upstream cache gets cleared.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 ecokrypt.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 1812
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ecokrypt.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ecokrypt.com.       3599    IN  A   13.232.131.162

;; Query time: 406 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 16 07:37:36 IST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 57
```

Comment: You have online troubleshooting tools: http://dnsviz.net/d/ecokrypt.com/XD9I7w/dnssec/. they show your domain as OK. Also when asking for help, "I tried making some changes" is not really descriptive. And if you did tests just before your changes you polluted the cache and hence you will see changes only after the TTL expires. https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/ecokrypt.com also shows your IP "everywhere".

Comment: Above 2 links are very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to clear your DNS cache. DNS results (including not found results) can persist in cache for some time.  What's worse, is that those results can be cached by upstream DNS servers, so even if you clear your local cache it might take anywhere from an hour to a day for the changes to propagate across the network.

A good way to test your DNS config is to force resolution using a well-behaved DNS server.

If you're using `dig` on a *nix box, it'd be something like:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 foo.com
```

`8.8.8.8` is the google DNS resolution service.

You can also use your resolution service directly:

```
dig @ns67.domaincontrol.com foo.com
```

Comment: For whatever it's worth, it looks to be resolving correctly from my current laptop.

Comment: Tried both above commands and it seems fine to me (updated my question), so looks like I have to wait till upstream cache gets cleared. Or is there any way to force clear this cache ?

Comment: Regrettably,  no.  The best you can do is to change your local DNS resolver to something well behaved such as `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Why is `8.8.8.8` more well-behaved than others? It has a cache like any other resolver, as caching is a core feature of the DNS.

Comment: The 8.8.8.8 servers tend to refresh ahead of the TTL (observation - I have no direct knowledge of the configuration).  There are lots of others, particularly in Asia, which cache beyond the TTL (misbehaving).